# making my character Tpose

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, proportional-editing

hey all so  a quick question for that
is there a way to my character acting as a T pose?
I have already modelled my character but I Don t want to mess anything by moving the arms or use propotional editing for it , I just want to know if there an easier way or better way to make it as t pose
thanks in advance[image]

sorry for the image content

Comment: You can do it with the Pose brush in Sculpt mode

Comment: You could also just rig it, and adjust the bones in Pose mode to whatever pose you want.